# Parse XML response coming from http get request using urllib3

Tags: python, xml, rest, urllib

I want to parse XML data coming from http get request from the following code:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', 'http://192.168.1.110:8083/GetSectors?which=3')
print(response.data)
print(response.status)
```

But the response is not as I desired.See below;

b'{"SectorList":null,"HataKodu":0,"HataMesaji":"Parametre belirlenen aral\xc4\xb1k d\xc4\xb1\xc5\x9f\xc4\xb1ndayd\xc4\xb1."}'
200

Now I want to parse it and get items one by one. I decided to use `urllib3`. But I couldn't be able to parse this data. Any idea ?

EDIT: My Python version is 3.4.4

The output in browser as below;

[output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5eww.png)

Comment: This doesn't look like XML, it's JSON. have you tried `import json` and `parsed = json.loads(response.data)`? Also, see the requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ - it turnes out to be useful when doing HTTP in Python.

Comment: Actually when i see in browser it seems xml and yes I tried first what you said but it couldnt get the items and I thought that the problem is the response is xml not JSON. Now I am little bit confused about the type of respond. I will put the screenshot with editing my post

Comment: Since that looks like JSON, I'd recommend the `requests` library which automatically parses GET data. It's also a lot easier to use than `urllib3`.

Comment: I used requests now I got the error; Traceback    print('{} {}'.format(todo_item['HataKodu'], todo_item['HataMesaji']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers. The same code was working for another example. But in this example it gives the error. So I dont know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By obeying the advices I used requests lib. But the only thing that I was forgat that I did not get the array but I tried to get an array object from the json respond. Thanks to everyone @Wojciech Ptak , @OrangeFlash81

Working code is below:

```
import requests
import json
resp = requests.get('http://192.168.1.110:8083/GetSectors?which=3')
print(resp.json()['HataMesaji'])
print(resp.json()['HataKodu'])
```

I can get any items like that.